# Maximum of rational functions with same denominators

Tags: maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose I have the following condition:

$$\max \left\{ \frac{f(x)}{h(x)},\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \right\}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
where $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ are all non-negative (real) functions. Is it theoretically correct to  state that this is equivalent to:
$$\frac{\max \left\{ f(x),g(x)\right\}}{h(x)}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
I'm having some trouble proving this. Your help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed the problem (functions of only one variable $x$). All functions are non-negative. Why would it not be correct?

Comment: The role of $x$ is not clear.  Is this for a particular $x$, or are you maximizing over all $x$?  In the former case your question is the same as is $\max[a/c, b/c] = max[a,b]/c$. If $c>0$ then, yes.

Comment: Yes, good point. I think I am not writing the problem properly...I'll reformulate

Comment: You need to have $h(x)>0$ for all $x$, since $h(x)=0$ makes the expressions undefined. In general $\max[ad,bd] = d\max[a,b]$ whenever $d>0$. So indeed for all $x$, if $h(x)>0$, you can pull $1/h(x)$ out of the max.  Here $x$ is a fixed quantity, not an optimization variable.

Comment: Indeed, $h(x)$ is non-negative. In that case, would the expressions be equivalent?

Comment: You can prove that if $a,b,d$ are real numbers with $d>0$ then $a \geq b$ if and only if $ad \geq bd$. That can prove the equality I stated, and if $h(x)>0$ then $1/h(x)>0$.

Comment: I see...great, thanks!